# SUM one tables fields based on another tables field

Tags: mysql, sum

I need to sum all of the price fields in the ORDER_ITEMS table only when the ORDER table's matching is_paid field is not 0000-00-00.

```
ORDER_ITEMS table
id
price

ORDER table
id
is_paid
```

example table data would be:

```
ORDER_ITEMS
id   price
1    1.25
1    0.75

2    1.25
2    0.50
2    2.50

ORDER
id   is_paid
1    0000-00-00
2    2013-02-27
```

so the above data would return:
id: 2
sum: 4.25

since id 1 is not paid (therefore dont care what the sum of price is) and id 2 is paid so we do care what the sum of id 2's price fields are.

thank you so much

Comment: I would suggest you to store `NULL` instead of `0000-00-00` for simplicity and better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need to use the `sum()` aggregate function and `GROUP BY` each order id:

```
select o.id, sum(oi.price) Total
from orders o
inner join ORDER_ITEMS oi
  on o.id = oi.id
where o.is_paid != '0000-00-00'
group by o.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff92b/4)

Answer (score 0):

If you need sum of all orders which are not '0000-00-00', remove "group by" from  bluefeet's code

the code will be 
select o.id, sum(oi.price) Total
from orders o
inner join ORDER_ITEMS oi
  on o.id = oi.id
where o.is_paid != '0000-00-00'

if you need order id wise sum, bluefeet's code is correct.